# Does the letter C by itself make the sound /kə/ in any word besides Cthulhu?

Tags: pronunciation

Cthulhu has two common pronunciations:

- /kəˈθuːluː/
- /kəˈtuːluː/

In both cases, the grapheme C represents the sound /kə/.

I can not think of any other word where the grapheme C represents the sound /kə/.  The RP pronunciation of "chthonic" comes the closest, but that word uses a CH grapheme to represent just the /k/ sound (as in words like "chaos" or "chorus").  As far as I'm aware, there is no vowel sound added to the initial /k/ phoneme in "chthonic".  (In fact, in the US the /k/ sound is often skipped entirely and the word pronounced /ˈθɑnɪk/.)

Does the letter C by itself make the sound /kə/ in any word besides Cthulhu?

Comment: **MODERATOR WARNING**: Got an answer? Post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The informal contraction **"c'mon"** is pronounced /kəˈmɒn/ according to [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%27mon); clearly the "c'" is pronounced as /kə/. Of course, that may not count due to the apostrophe.

I have also heard some people pronounce **"clearly"** as /kəˈlɪɹli/ ("kuh-LEAR-ly") when it is meant sarcastically. But I can't find a reference for that online.

Comment: Great examples - thank you!!  

c'mon: I agree about the apostrophe changing things... sometimes it can make a schwa sound, as in it'd.

clearly: Love this, thank you!!

Comment: "Clearly" is not the only such word; there is also crazy ("kuh-RAY-zee"), for example, and the same can be done with some other words, too.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Indeed. Curiously, I can't find any articles about this online. Maybe it's a new phenomenon? (I'm in the Northeast US, in case it's a regional thing.)

Comment: @alphabet I'm sure there must be a term for it, but I don't know what it would be. I did find this in a quick search, though, which is quite apropos for this site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9NrqkIcrMQ

Answer (score 3):

My dictionary lists
*cnemial

Cnedaria

cnedarian*
all pronounced with the *c* silent.  And
*Cnut*
(Danish king of England, 1017-1035).  This one is nowadays written *Canute*, but I'm guessing before 1035 is was still spelled *Cnut*.

Comment: "Cnut" is a case where the traditional anglicization is *Canute,* but modern scholars often disregard that and use *Cnut* instead to be closer to the original spelling. See the Wikipedia article and its talk page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnut

Comment: OED says the pronunciation of *cnemial* is /kn-/, and can be /kn-/ for the others. The *c* is not silent. However, *cten-* does have a silent *c* and is pronounced /tiːn-/.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Well, the OED can say that, but there isn't really any reason for there to be a distinction between "cnemial" and other words of Greek origin starting with "cn-", and *cnemial* definitely has or at least has had pronunciations where the "c" is silent. Here's a dictionary from 1901 that gives the pronunciation of "cnemial" as "ne´-me-al": [A Pocket Medical Dictionary, by George Milbry Gould](https://books.google.com/books?id=NSS6AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA170)

Answer (score 0):

This is from [Wikipedia...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu#Etymology,_spelling,_and_pronunciation)

> Invented by Lovecraft in 1928, the name ***Cthulhu*** was probably chosen to echo the word ***chthonic*** (Ancient Greek "of the earth"), as apparently suggested by Lovecraft himself

So obviously there are at least *four* "words" I can pull out of the full [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/32647) straight away...

> ***chthonian, chthonic, chthonography, chthononosology***

...but equally obviously, it's a matter of opinion whether we accept any or all of those as "English" words

I've no idea how the ancient Greeks pronounced their "original", but it's unnatural for Anglophones to enunciate "hard C" (K) followed by another consonant without an intervening schwa, so we wouldn't normally try to *write* it like that. We write ***ker-ching**!* for the onomatopoeic sound of a cash register, not ***c-ching**!* or ***cching**!*.

---

If you feed the 3-character sequence **"C" [consonant] [asterisk]** into [OneLook Dictionary Search](https://www.onelook.com/?w=cnidarian) you should be able to find hundreds more candidate words. I just went for **CN*** because I knew ***Cnidaria***, but the OED has ***cnemial, cnicin, cnicnode, cnida, cnidarian*** in that section, and most if not all of those have at least the *option* of enunciating the hard C.

Answer (score 0):

I would analyze this as a consonant cluster in the spelling; you may make a vowel sound between them, but it isn't just the c making it: it's a join between c and th.

because they aren't usually together in one English syllable, they're joined with a schwa

Comment: The "Greek original" had **ch** + **th**, which I certainly can't enunciate without an intervening schwa. But I can do **ph** + **th** without too much trouble (in, for example, **Diphthong**).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I interpret diphthong as having two syllables: /ˈdɪfˌθɔŋ/.  Given that, I think the ph and th are each in their own syllable... not in a cluster?

Comment: @kanamekun How about *phthalate*?

Comment: in phthalate, I believe the phth grapheme normally represents just the sound /θ/ as in /ˈθæl.eɪt/.  A similar case may be apophthegm, which is typically pronounced /ˈæ.pə.θɛm/... and the ph sometimes dropped to spell it just apothegm.